# How to rename the function using query in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am created  one function as Test1(). I want to rename the function as Test11().

```
   Create  function dbo.Test1()
     returns Datetime
     AS
       BEGIN 
    return (SELECT GETDATE())
    END
    GO
  SELECT  dbo.Test1()
```

If possible to rename the function name using query.

Answer (score 8):

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Test1','Test11',object
--1st parameter=Original object name
--2nd parmeter=New name
--3rd parmeter=Objecttype to rename(object,column,index)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing it with T-SQL, you'll have to `DROP` the function and recreate it afterwards:

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Test1;
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test11()
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT GETDATE())
END
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510244.aspx):

> **To rename user-defined functions**
>
> This task cannot be performed using Transact-SQL statements. To rename a user-defined function using Transact-SQL, you must first delete the existing function and then re-create it with the new name. Ensure that all code and applications that used the function’s old name now use the new name.

Comment: without drop. If possible to rename..@diiN_

Comment: @Meline MSDN says that you can't rename it without dropping it first.

Answer (score 2):

To rename user-defined functions
This task cannot be performed using Transact-SQL statements. To rename a user-defined function using Transact-SQL, you must first delete the existing function and then re-create it with the new name. Ensure that all code and applications that used the function’s old name now use the new name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510244.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to rename a procedure/function unless you drop and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

This task cannot be performed using Transact-SQL statements. To rename a user-defined function using Transact-SQL, you must first delete the existing function and then re-create it with the new name. Ensure that all code and applications that used the function’s old name now use the new name